# How to check Zookeeper connection in HBase?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I want to do a quick connection check with Zookeeper after creating my configurations and before establishing connection to my HBase master from Java code.
Which HBase API method is good for checking the Zookeeper connection status in my cluster?

Comment: Do you mean checking whether the HBase cluster connection to Zookeeper is good or checking whether Zookeeper is up from your Java code?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code

```
Configuration config =  HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hbase");
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
```

After you configured the connection, you can test it, using

```
HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);
```

It will test the connection to your database, if Zookeeper doesn't work you will get an error printed saying there is a problem with Zookeeper.